# WPF listbox item not wordwrapping

Tags: .net, wpf, listbox, word-wrap

My `ListBox` has, amongst other things a description field in it which can be quite long. Instead of having a horizontal scroll bar I want to word wrap it.
It works if I set the `MaxWidth` but since the `ListBox` changes size I don't want to hard code the value.

What's the best way to do this?

EDIT: The description is in a `TextBlock`.

Simplified XAML (Removed unnessesary stuff, still shows problem:

```
         <ListBox BorderThickness="0" Padding="5" Name="lstTasks">
            <ListBox.ItemsSource>
                <Binding Source="{StaticResource dataTasks}"/>
            </ListBox.ItemsSource>

            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=RequestDescription}" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" TextWrapping="Wrap" Height="60" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Comment: Since you said setting MaxWidth would work, how about binding that MaxWidth to something that is causing the width to change?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Try forcing the width of your ListBoxItems to be the width of the ListBox:

```
<ListBox
     Name="lstTasks"
     BorderThickness="0"
     Padding="5"
     HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
```

Also you might try disabling horizontal scrolling:

```
<ListBox
     ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
     ...>
```

Comment: Thanks, disabling the Scroll Bar fixed it instantly.

Comment: If it worked for you, upvote. Stack comments are not ebay ratings.

Comment: +1 Setting the scrollbar visibility seems to limit the width of the contained controls to the bounds of your listbox. Weird but true.

Comment: Don't confuse "Disabled" with "Hidden"! That was my mistake. "Hidden" means there's still a scrollbar, you just can't see it.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't meaning of using wrapping and trimming together. You should use one of them texttrimming or textwrapping. It it trims it doesn't wrap.

For textwrapping Matt's answer is correct for trimming you should define **width** or **maxwidth** property value.

Its exactly the same for SL developers.